# compare AVG(integer) with AVG(integer) of a category

Tags: mysql, sql

i have relation with three columns: `ProductName`, `CategoryID` and `Price`. i need to `SELECT` only those products which `Price` is higher than average product `Price` in given category.
(eg when `apple`(`ProductName`) is a `fruit`(`CategoryID`) it should be selected because its price is higher than average fruit price). How do i do that?

I'm thinking of something like this, but its obviously wrong since I'm comparing `Price` with `Price` and `CategoryID`:

```
SELECT ProductName, AVG(Price) FROM `products` 
WHERE (SELECT AVG(Price)) > (SELECT CategoryID, AVG(Price))
GROUP BY ProductName;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
SELECT ProductName, Price, CategoryID FROM `products` p
WHERE Price > (SELECT AVG(Price) from `products` where  CategoryID = p.CategoryID)
```